# Can I ask about career in industry?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask about career change: going from a postdoc researcher in the field of biomedical devices into industry. Could I ask it here? This is the only place that has the tag related to biomedical devices. Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Career and education advice is off-topic for the site.  It ends up being either primarily opinion based or of insufficient use to future visitors or both.

Thanks for asking in advance on meta.